# Invalid use of group function - MySQL using COALESCE

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, coalesce

I want a database table with links that are used to generate the navigation on a website. For instance, the text 'Home' will link to 'http://example.com/home' and the text 'Twitter' will  link to the Twitter URL, etc. I also wanted to be able to change the order in which the links are presented, hence the `order` column. I also want to be able to edit the links, that's why I'm using auto_incremented `id`'s.

Now I want `order` to be unique, so my plan was to get the max of `order` and just add one. This is the query I'm using, but it will return: `Invalid use of group function`

```
INSERT INTO
  `links`
  (`id`, `order`, `text`, `html_text`, `link`, `html_link`)
VALUES
  (NULL, COALESCE((MAX(`order`) + 1), 1), 'text', 'text (html)', 'url', 'url (html)');
```

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `html_text` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `html_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

How do I get a valid query doing just what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one shot, you'll have to do an `INSERT ... SELECT` combination to get the value from the database and insert based on it;

```
INSERT INTO
  `links`
  (`id`, `order`, `text`, `html_text`, `link`, `html_link`)
SELECT
  NULL, COALESCE((MAX(`order`) + 1), 1), 'text', 'text (html)', 'url', 'url (html)'
FROM `links`;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb05/1).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll approve this as the answer in a few minutes! I've been looking for a solution for over 30 minutes, gave up, posted this and you answered within minutes! Thanks :)